# what Usb installer is available on the raspberry pi?

Tags: usb, raspbian-stretch, hard-drive

I recently bought a new computer without an OS on it, and I have just the raspberry pi right now, it's a 3b (not b+) and I want to burn an ISO onto a flash drive (specifically ubuntu budgie) however the tool I used before for this, Unetbootin, is not available on the pi, is there a tool I can use?
I have heard you can use the dd command but I am not fluent enough in linux to risk overwriting my partition. 
If someone could suggest a tool, or help me step by step with the DD command I would appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: not available for the pi

Answer (score 1):

If you use p7zip to unpack the zipped image file you can write it to an SDCard or USB stick with `sudo dd if=/home/pi/unpacked_image_file of=/dev/sda` [You need to be 100% certain that /dev/sda is the right place as `dd` takes no prisoners.]

Comment: I'm looking for a tool first if you know of one